# delete the last item of a list using jQuery with Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, server

I'm creating a basic web application and would like to add and remove items from a list. Currently adding items is fine and removing items is fine until I try to remove the last item I get a 500 internal server error.

My controller looks like this:

```
class BudgetsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_project, :set_team, :set_budgets except: [:destroy]

def create
    @budget = @team.budgets.create(budget_params)
    @team = Team.where(params[:id]).first_or_initialize
    @team.team_budget = @budgets.first.sum(@budgets).to_f
    @team.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_team_path(@project, @team) }
      format.js { }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @budget = @team.budgets.find(params[:id])
    @budget.destroy
    if @budgets.first.sum(@budgets).to_f.nil?
       @team.team_budget = 2
    else
    @team.team_budget = (@budgets.first.sum(@budgets).to_f)
    end
   @team.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_team_path(@project, @team) }
      format.js { }
    end
  end

  private

  def set_budgets
    @budgets = @team.budgets.all
  end

  def set_team
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
  end

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end
```

My jQuery method looks like this:

```
$("li#<%= @budget.id %>").slideUp();
$('#budget_total').text("<%= @budgets.first.sum(@budgets) %>");
```

My budget partial looks like this:

```
<li id="<%= budget.id %>">
  <%= budget.budget_item %>
  <%= budget.quantity %>
  <%= budget.cost_per_item %>
  Total cost: <%= budget.quantity * budget.cost_per_item %>
  <%= link_to "delete budget item", project_team_budget_path(@project, @team, budget), method: 'delete', remote: true %>
</li>
```

My index partial looks like this:

```
<h1>My Estimated Budget</h1>
<% if @budgets.any? %>
<h3>Total Budget: <b id="budget_total"><%=@budgets.first.sum(@budgets) %></b></h3>
<% else %>
<h3>Total Budget: <b id="budget_total">0.0</b></h3>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@project, @team, @budget], remote: true do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :budget_item %>
    <%= f.text_field :budget_item %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :quantity %>
    <%= f.number_field :quantity %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :cost_per_item %>
    <%= f.number_field :cost_per_item %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" id="add_item">
  <%= f.submit "Create Budget Item"%>
  </div>
<% end %>

<ul class="budget_items">
  <%= render @budgets %>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've tried different jQuery syntax (FadeOut, Remove) and :last child. And also have tried the destroy method without the conditional.

Comment: There should be something in your logs to go with that server error.

Comment: We did some changes in the destroy.js.erb now we have a problem within our budget controller:

NoMethodError (undefined method `any?' for #<Budget:0x007faffea30e70>):
 app/controllers/budgets_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'

Comment: Ans what does that line 18 looks like? `.any?` has to be called on a relation (`Budget.all`, `Budget.where(condition)`...), not on a single reccord (`Budget.find(condition)`, `Budget.where(condition).first()`...)

Comment: Your `destroy` is assuming that `@budgets` will be set but you say `:set_budgets except: [:destroy]`...